# Did crown chests stop stacking from the last update in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

This might be a bug or a new feature but if you miss a crown chest, do they still stack for 2 chests?  I don't think it stacks anymore.

I just noticed this weekend.  I got busy and couldn't play from Friday morning until Monday morning.  I just filled my crown chest but the 2nd chest I should have gotten for missing the last 3 days was not there.  My cooldown for the crown chest said I could get the next one in several hours.

No one else has touched my game so no crown chests were won/gained.  Is this a bug from the new release or a change in the rules?  The [wiki](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Chests) still says it stacks for 2 missing chests but I found from my experience this weekend to not be the case.

Am I crazy or have others seen this behavior too?

Comment: I just earned a crown chest, and had another one waiting to be earned myself (hadn't played it in a couple days).  Nothing official, but it appears to have not changed.

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife, thx.  i don't know what happened with myself then.  thx for verifying for me.

Comment: if you can find patch notes for the last update, the change would be documented in it, so if it doesnt say anything about it, you can probably assume it hasnt changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crown Chests stack up to 2 chests total, and then you have to wait. If you only get one, this is usually due to a glitch or a server issue.

[I got 2x Crown Chest in 1 day on 4/6/2017, so it's not a removal.]